# Trouble Showing SnackBar After API Call on AlertDialog 'Yes' Button Click in Flutter

Tags: flutter, provider

I'm facing an issue in a Flutter application where I want to display a SnackBar after making an API call following an 'Yes' button click in an AlertDialog. The workflow is as follows:

1. User taps a button, triggering an AlertDialog.
2. In the AlertDialog,the user has the option to click 'Yes'. Upon clicking 'Yes', I need
   to immediately close the AlertDialog and start making an API call.
3. During the API call, I want to display a loading indicator on the screen.
4. After the API call is complete, I want to show a SnackBar
   based on the result.

The problem I'm encountering is that after I
pop    the AlertDialog to show the SnackBar, the context is null,
which is    preventing me from displaying the SnackBar.

```
class MyProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _loader = false;

  bool get loader => _loader;

  Future<bool> fakeApiCall() async {
    _loader = true;
    notifyListeners();

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
    _loader = false;
    notifyListeners();

    return true;
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myProvider = context.watch<MyProvider>();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: myProvider.loader
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        content: const Text("Alert"),
                        actions: [
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                              context
                                  .read<MyProvider>()
                                  .fakeApiCall()
                                  .then((value) {
                                if (value) {
                                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                      const SnackBar(
                                          content: Text("Snackbar Showed")));
                                }
                              });
                            },
                            child: const Text("Yes"),
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
                child: const Text("Tap"),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried different approaches, including passing the BuildContext and using GlobalKey, but I haven't been able to resolve this issue.

I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to properly manage the context so that I can display the SnackBar after the API call.

Answer (score 0):

Your can make a widget that handles the button and on click shows the alert when you click 'Yes' on the alert pop the context then use a callback function passed as a parameter to you widget.

```
TextButton(
 onPressed: () async {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    callApiFunction();
},
```

Now in the parent widget class where you are calling your new custom widget you can implement the callback there which calls the api and shows the snackBar.